# How to align elements with different height to the top AND to the bottom in table cells?

Tags: html, css, drupal, layout, alignment

I'm working on a Drupal site that promotes rural products and services of several vendors. On the main page I display a few items in a grid, each on a 'product card' (vendor, address, phone, product image, product name, price, 'Buy now' button). Since each part of these attributes of a product may has different lenght, the layout of the page is very confused (see this screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/2i1ede9/5).

Actually I have two questions about this issue:

1. Is there any web designing method how to display elements of different height in fix-sized containers nicely? Is it possible to level their height?
2. How should I align one div (vm_prod_cat) to the top and the other (offsite_selling) to the bottom of the cell? This can solve my problem more or less: a given compontent of product cards (e.g. address of vendors) won't be of equal height, but the layout would look balanced. I tried to add the `display: inline-block;` and `the vertical-align: top;` or `vertical-align: bottom;` attributes but they didn't worked for me.

Drupal generates the grid with these table cells and divs:

```
<tr class="row-3 row-last">
<td class="col-1 col-first">
<td class="col-2">
<div class="vm_prod_cat prod_cat_tur">
<div>
<div class="views-field views-field-uc-product-image">
<div class="vm_product">
<div class="offsite_selling">
</td>
<td class="col-3 col-last">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the display:table family rules to have boxes behaving like tables :

```
.gal {
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  min-width:350px;
}
.gal article {
  display:inline-table;
  height:300px;
  width:30%;
  min-width:100px;
  box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em,
    inset 0 0 0 1px;;
  margin:10px;
}
.gal article > header ,
.gal article > footer ,
.gal article > div {
  display:table-row;
  padding:0.5em;
  background:gray
}
.gal article > div {
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```
<section class="gal">
  <article>
    <header>
      header that takes room it needs
    </header>
    <div>
      content that takes room left
    </div>
    <footer>
      footer that takes room needed
    </footer>
  </article>
<!-- ... and so on -->
```

see test here : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ALifh

each article may grow alone. To avoid them to grow on their width, add `table-layout:fixed;`, nothing will stop them growing on their height. You need to set a minimal safe height.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However it's still not working: Adding the display:table-row; to the <div class="vm_prod_cat prod_cat_tur">, the logo from the top of the box hascompletely disappeared. (The logo is a background image with an explicit height)

Comment: then you need to just give it an explicit height and insert an &nbsp; caractere. With this content, the browser will wrap it in an element with display:table-ceel; value (just like a <tbody> is added to a HTML table when not written in code. Demo updated :)

Comment: Finally I managed to solve this issue, thanks a lot! Besides the alignment I had to remove a border-collapse: separate; decalaration (which ruined the layout completely) and add an inner wrapper to the footer (the dark brown box) with a display:block; in order to be able to add margins and paddings.